# How to compile Hex-Rays decompiler generated code?

Tags: decompilation, ida, compilers

I need help to compile Pseudo-C code generated with IDA Pro and the Hex-Rays decompiler plugin. It shows an error on this line:

```
int (__thiscall *off_401F14)(void *, char); // weak
```

Error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
```

I don't see any error on that line. What's wrong?

Comment: Which compiler (and version) are you trying this in? Please edit your question. Also, this looks off-topic as it concerns forward engineering - and yes, I realize that the tool used is mainly used in RCE.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I agree that the question lack vital information, However, I find this question related to the site. Decompiler are part of the RE process, and compiling the output is absolutly relevant to RE.

Comment: it will not solve your problem, of a missing call type, but you should include "defs.h"  ( found in the hexrays sdk )  in your file, it contains several macros used by hexrays.

Comment: o, and what is wrong,  is that '__thiscall'  is apparently not defined for your compiler, you should '#define __thiscall'   it to nothing to get rid of this specific error

Answer (score 6):

The following code compiles just fine for me as a `.cpp` file in Visual C++:

```
int (__thiscall *off_401F14)(void *, char); // weak

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Perhaps you placed the function prototype inside of a function by accident or compiled it as C (file extension `.c`) file?

Comment: you obviously made assumptions about the compiler, so you should add on which compiler (and version) this *compiles just fine*.

Comment: I didn't make assumptions about his compiler...
"error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'" is a VC++ compiler error, and I tested my code above with VC++.

Comment: it likely is, I agree. But which version? Also it depends (the `__thiscall`) whether you throw it into a `.cpp` or a `.c` file ;) ... you mention neither and neither does the OP. I find the *question* extremely badly worded.

Comment: Actually, you raise a very good point. It looks like it could be because the OP was using a .c file instead of a .cpp file.